# Alternative solution for integral limit using mean theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, mean-value-theorem

Let $$  I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+1}dx $$
I would like to know whether it's possible to prove that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} I_{n} = 0 $$ using the mean theorem for integrals.

It is quite straightforward to prove the limit is 0 as follows from below:

$$ 0\leq I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+1}dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Thus by the squeeze theorem we can conclude $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} I_{n} = 0 $$

However, I am having a hard time to prove the same result using the mean theorem for integrals. By the mean theorem we know that for each n, there exists $ c_{n} \in [0, 1] $ such that $ I_{n} = f(c_{n}) $ where $f:[0, \infty) \to [0, 1)$ is defined as $$ f(x) = \frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+1}$$

Furthermore actually each such $ c_{n}$ cannot be either 0 or 1, thus $ c_{n} \in (0,1) \hspace{1mm} \forall n$. Indeed this follows from the below reasoning:

It can be easily verified that $ (I_{n})_{n\geq1} $ is a decreasing sequence and since $$ I_{1} = 1 - \ln(2) < \frac{1}{3}$$ it follows that $ I_{n} < \frac{1}{3} \forall n \geq 1$. Suppose there exists an $ n = n_{0}$ for which $ c_{n_{0}} = 1 $, then $$ I_{n_{0}} = f(c_{n_{0}}) = f(1) = \frac{1}{2} $$ which contradicts the above condition.

Suppose now that there exists an $ n = n_{1}$ for which $ c_{n_{1}} = 0 $. Then it follows that  $$ I_{n_{1}} = f(c_{n_{1}}) = f(0) = 0 $$ But this cannot occur since $$ I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+1}dx \geq  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{2}dx = \frac{1}{2(n+1)} > 0 \quad \forall n \geq 1$$

Therefore $ c_{n} \in (0,1) \forall n \geq 1 $. Let's also show that the sequence $ (c_{n})_{n \geq 1} $ is decreasing. Indeed, we have the following:

$$ I_{n} = f(c_{n}) \geq I_{n+1} = f(c_{n+1}) $$ But f is a strictly increasing function on $ (0,1) $ which can be easily verified by computing its derivative. Therefore it must hold that $ c_{n} \geq c_{n+1} \forall n \geq 1$ hence $ (c_{n})_{n \geq 1} $ is decreasing and since it is also bounded in $ (0, 1) $, it must be convergent via the monotone convergence theorem.

Let $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} c_{n} = l$$ I think it would then be enough to show that this limit cannot be 1 so that we could conclude that $ I_{n} $ converges to 0. Indeed, if $ l< 1$ then we must have $ l \in [0, 1)$ since $ c_{n} \in (0, 1) \forall n \geq 1$ and thus we have: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} I_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(c_{n}) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} c_{n}) = f(l) = \frac{l^{n}}{l^{n}+1} $$ and the last term in the RHS above converges to 0 when $ n $ goes to infinity.

I don't know  whether or not $ l $ can also be equal to 1 and also if my reasoning above for the conclusion that the desired limit is 0 for $ l \in [0, 1) $ is entirely correct. Could someone help me regarding this? Thank you so much!

Comment: 1. The mean value theorem for integrals actually includes the conclusion that $c_n$ is in the interior, so you don't need to prove that $c_n\neq 0$ and $c_n\neq 1$. It comes from the mean value theorem which comes from Rolle's theorem, which is about interior extrema. 

2. Your reasoning that if $l<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{l^n}{l^n+1}=0$ is good. However, if you already proved that $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is non-increasing and $c_1<1$, then we know that each $c_n\leqslant c_1<1$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n\leqslant c_1<1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Indeed, now I see that $ l < 1 $.

Comment: Since l must be less then 1 the limit always goes to zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AidanR.S. Indeed, yes, the limit will go to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above by @jwhite, if $(c_n)$ was decreasing, you wouldn't need to prove that $l<1$. Anyway, your attempt is flawed because you are acting (twice) as if $f$ was a fixed function, not depending on $n$.

If, instead, you write
$$\forall x\in[0,1],\quad f_{\color{red}n}(x):=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n},$$
you will realize that:

1. the monotonicity of each $f_n$ and the fact that $f_n(c_n)=I_n>I_{n+1}=f_{n+1}(c_{n+1})$ don't suffice to prove that the sequence $(c_n)$ is decreasing (actually, I believe it is increasing and converges to $1$). Even the additional fact that $(f_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of functions does not help.
2. even if $(c_n)$ converges, your "$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(c_{n}) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} c_{n})$" is not salvageable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the first point. However, I don't quite follow point 2. For each $ n $, the function $ f_{n} $ is continuous thus it commutes with the limit of $ c_{n} $ if $ (c_{n}) $ converges.  Or is the issue coming from the fact that there is a limit on the sequence of functions $ f_{n} $ and a different one on the sequence $ (c_{n}) $ ?

Also could you share please why you think $ (c_{n}) $ is increasing and converges to 1? Thank you so much!

Comment: $f_n$ cannot commute with $\lim c_n$ because $f_n$ depends on $n$, like $c_n$. You cannot write $\lim f_n(c_n)=f_n(\lim c_n)$, it would mean $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(c_k)=f_n(\lim_{j\to\infty} c_j)$. As for my guess about the behaviour of $(c_n)$, it is motivated by a glance ant the plots of $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_9$.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!